# ASP.NET MVC3 Ajax: InsertionMode.Replace not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm new to MVC, and liking it, but have run into an issue. I've got a View with code like this:

```
@model MyModel

@Ajax.ActionLink("Add", "Create", "User", null, 
    new AjaxOptions { 
        UpdateTargetId = "mydiv", 
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
        HttpMethod = "GET"
    }, 
    new {
        @class = "add"
    })

<div>
    @Html.Partial("UserTable", Model.RegisteredUsers)
</div>

<div id="mydiv" />
```

This is probably pretty obvious, but the page displays a list of users (the "UserTable" partial view) and includes a link for the admin to click to create a new user. The create user form is a partial view that acts like a popup window over the UserTable. Here's the controller action that returns the create user form:

```
public string Create()
{
    Models.User user = new Models.User();
    PartialViewResult vr;
    ViewContext vc;
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    vr = PartialView("../../Views/User/UserForm", user);
    vr.ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
    vc = new ViewContext(this.ControllerContext, vr.View, vr.ViewData, new TempDataDictionary(), sw);
    vr.View.Render(vc sw);

    return "<div style=\"position:absolute; top:200px; left:175px\">" + sw.ToString() + "</div>";
}
```

The reason I'm returning a string instead of an ActionResult (or something like that) is to add the wrapper div that creates the "popup" effect. This all works perfectly, except that, in addition to showing up in the "popup," the create user form also shows up below the UserTable, where "mydiv" is. An examination of the page source shows that "mydiv" is not being replaced, but rather, the code for the create user form is being placed both in that div *and* in the new popup div, and I'm having no luck figuring out why.

I think I'm referencing the correct jQuery libraries:

```
<script src="@Url.Contetn("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Contetn("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this behavior and how to fix it? Or is there a better approach to achieving the same effect that you can recommend?

TIA!

Jeff

**EDIT:**

Oh, forgot to mention: the reason I can't just put the "popup" div in the create user form itself is that it's used in other places in the system, and that behavior is not desirable there. I didn't create that form myself, just reusing another dev's code in my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured this out. I misunderstood what the `Render` method in the controller action was doing. It should've been obvious, but it actually writes the partial view to the page. It got written again, this time with the "popup" div, when the action returned.

I found another way to handle this, though. As I mentioned, I couldn't modify the create user form directly, but I created another partial view and added the create user form to it via `@Html.Partial`, all wrapped in the popup div. Then all I had to do was return this "derived" partial view from the controller action and it worked like a charm.

Anyway, just thought I'd post this in case anyone ever finds themselves in a similar situation.

Jeff